# Delete if record exists and Insert if record doesn't exist

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

In my for loop, I'm writing an Insert and delete query which does the following:

In the case if the checkbox is not check then check if the record exist & if it exist then delete.  If it doesn’t exist then don’t do anything.

If checkbox is check then also check if record exist & if it exist then don’t do anything but if it doesn’t exist then insert it.

I need a check on whether my queries, especially my subqueries would execute properly or would return an error because I'm writing it without wanting to change my database right now.

```
For Each oDataGridItem In valgrid2.Items
        chk = oDataGridItem.FindControl("CheckBox1")
        rn = oDataGridItem.FindControl("lblrptName")
        rid = oDataGridItem.FindControl("lblReportID")
        If chk.Checked = True Then
            rpti = CType(oDataGridItem.FindControl("lblReportID"), Label).Text

            'valsql2 = "INSERT INTO CompanyReportListTable(CompanyID, ReportID) Values (valCompanyId, rpti) WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CompanyReportListTable WHERE ReportID <> rpti and companyid <> valCompanyId and " & chk.Checked & "= 1)"
            'if it exists then don’t do anything
            'valsql2 = valsq2 & ";IF ReportID = rpti and companyid = valCompanyId BEGIN WHERE CompanyID = CompanyID AND ReportID = ReportID END" 
            'To do nothing, i'd equal the parameter's value to the column name

            count += 1
            rptn = CType(oDataGridItem.FindControl("lblrptName"), Label).Text
            oExArgs.Add(rptn)
            Response.Write(rpti + " - " + rptn + "<br/>")
        Else
            'valsql2 = valsq2 & ";DELETE FROM CompanyReportListTable WHERE EXISTS(Select * FROM CompanyReportListTable WHERE ReportID = rpti and companyid = valCompanyId and" & chk.Checked & " = 0)"
            'if it doesn't exist then don’t do anything
            'valsql2 = valsq2 & ";IF ReportID <> rpti and companyid <> valCompanyId BEGIN WHERE CompanyID = CompanyID AND ReportID = ReportID END" 

        End If
```

Comment: Have you tried running them? What happens? Do you get an error? Does it change the right data?

Comment: I get an error from one of the subqueries, but I only ran once because I didn't want to change my database at that moment until I have written the proper statements.

Comment: What if the user checks both boxes?

Comment: Then both records in where the checkbox is checked would have to not exist in order for me to insert data into the columns. If both exist then do nothing.

Comment: It would be safest to make a copy of your database for development. You could write your SQL statements in SQL Server Management Studio so that you can get the correct syntax. I can see too many problems with your code as it is for me to list them and their possible resolutions.

Comment: what is your error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
valsql2 = "INSERT INTO CompanyReportListTable(CompanyID, ReportID) Values (valCompanyId, rpti) WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CompanyReportListTable WHERE ReportID <> rpti and companyid <> valCompanyId and " & chk.Checked & "= 1)"
```

In this code `" & chk.Checked & "= 1)"`will give error . **True =1** which is not support in sql .

Comment: Thanks Karthick. chk is at the front-end, and is not inside any of the columns or values, so it wouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 0):

There would be no need for a CASE statement if you don't want the code to do anything, for the CASE would work with the SELECT statement. Since the queries are under an If-Else statement, valsql2 = whatever, instead of valsql2 = valsql2 & ";" because this is a conditional statement and whatever the condition, so will the query be. The queries are fairly fine, just get rid of chk.Checked = 0 and chk.Checked = 1